# Position Absolute, "shadow / dotted box" not wrapped around the "div"

Tags: html, css, css-transforms

Very curious about why when I position something using css as per below example using position: absolute, the box around the div is offset to the bottom side:

```css
.e-mail {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 15;
    right: 10%;
    top: 60%;
    transform: translate(-10%, -60%);
}

.contact-form{
    background: #fefefe;
    padding: 10px;
    border-radius: 15px;
    max-width: 400px;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
 <div class="row mail">
                <div class="e-mail">
                    <form class="contact-form " action="#" method="post">
                        <h1>get a quote</h1>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="name" placeholder="Full Name">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" name="mail" placeholder="Your E-mail">
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <select class="form-control">
                                <option>Select Option</option>
                                <option>quote one</option>
                                <option>quote two</option>
                                <option>quote three</option>
                                <option>quote four</option>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        <button class="btn btn-primary mail-submit" type="submit" name="submit" style="width: 100%">Request Quote</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
```

the attached image will explain what i am referring too. Any suggestions why this would happen and does it effect anything or is it normal?

thanks[image: ![offset shadow box]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6smO.jpg)

Comment: simply because of the translation, you translate the element and not his parent

Comment: So in this case i should actually translate .contact-form class?

Comment: yes, try and see

Comment: ahh, Works. Thanks!